# Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.M5

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to add jpa dependency in my spring boot pom.xml file

I am getting red underline under dependency. When I hover over it shows

Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.M5

What to do?

Comment: Did you try maven update, it shall download the missing artifact.

Comment: I just did that. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try maven update, it shall download the missing artifact.